# What performance can I expect from such a query in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm wondering if this ,the strategy I will explain, would be recommended to use in Firebase.

I will first explain what my goal is, since I'm sure tons of others have solved the same problem already, and maybe some of you can tell me how it's usually done.

The goal is to notify all users of an App when the friend in common "George" (based on their contacts) is now also a proud new user of the App.

So, my idea was to do so:

1- Build a collection with this structure:

```
{
  "contacts": 
    {
      "user1":
      {
        {"user239":true}
        ,
        {"user23":false}
        ,
        {"user732":true}
      }
      ,
      {
       "user2" :
       {
        {"user23":false}
        ,
        {"user96":false}
        ,
        {"user88":true}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To save for each user a list of contacts.

Then the new user would query a list of contacts like this:

```
fbRef.child('contacts').orderByChild('user23').equalTo(false).once('value', showResults, console.error);
```

Then the user would save the results in a map, change the value to `true`, and then `updateChildren()` using that map.

Now, is this reasonable if we imagine that we aspire to have hundreds of thousands and even millions of users using the App?

How expensive would this be when we have 5M users and a few joining by the second?

Is there a known "best strategy" for this case?

Thanks

Comment: Keep this simple. Each user has a contacts node that contains contact info names (emails, phone numbers, whatever). Each user's app adds an observer to the main users node that contains all users. When George signs up his info is written to the main users node and each user will be notified of this new user. Compare that name (email, phone #) to their list of contacts and if it matches then add George's user id to the contact list. The hard part is determining what trigger you want to use that's granular enough to know it's the right George. Thousands of observers is no problem.

Comment: +1 to @Jay, I think it's correct answer. BTW, you will never get 5M of users with another f*cking what's app, and even if you do - it will be non-profit with firebase price. IMHO

Answer (score 0):

The real-time functions in Firebase are not only suited for, but designed for large data sets. The fact that records stream in real-time is perfect for this.

Performance is, as with any large data app, only as good as your implementation. So here are a few gotchas to keep in mind with large data sets.

So what you can do is **Denormalise** the data.

```
**/users/uid
/users/uid/profile
/users/uid/chat_messages
/users/uid/groups
/users/uid/audit_record**


**/user_profiles/uid
/user_chat_messages/uid
/user_groups/uid
/user_audit_records/uid**
```

Second approach is good for iterating large data sets that the first approach which is clearly visible.

Avoid calling the `value` on large data sets.Call it by the `child_used`
This helps to denormalize the data above.

Remember firebase can handle large amount of data but it depends upon the approach you follow.

For Example: if we want to store the 'last_logins' for any user we can directly store it under the specific object instance. It will provide ease of access when we want to access 'last_logins' for a particular user.

Maintaining **Many to Many** Relations

We have already seen that we cannot nest Users in Groups as it will not represent many to many relation and will leave redundant data. We can create an index of groups under a specific containing only the keys of the groups which a user belongs to. This will enable us to easily fetch list of groups to which a user belongs to.

Storing **One to Many Relations** or Static Lists

Here are the links to some of the best practices that must be used for a firebase design.

[Performance](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html)

[Indexing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data)